# Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and supposed that A is a subset of X. Then $Bd(A) = Cl(A) \cap Cl(X-A)$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $(X, \mathfrak T)$ be a topological space and supposed that A is a subset of X.  Then $Bd(A) = Cl(A) \cap Cl(X-A)$.

I know this is a true statement. I am trying to prove if because I would also like to use this definition to show that the boundary of a set is a closed set.

Here are my definitions, knowledge and attempt at the proof.  I am using the definitions and set theory to complete my proof by letting an element be in each side and then show it is in the other side.

Boundary of $A$ is the set of all points $x \in X$ for which every open set containing $x$ intersects both $X$ and $X-A$

Closure of $A$ is $Cl(A) = \bigcap \{U \subseteq X: U$ is a closed set and $A \subseteq U\}$. I know from my definition that $A \subset Cl(A)$

My attempt at the proof:

Let $x \in Bd(A)$ then there exists a set $X \in x$ that intersects both $X$ and $X-A$ since $A \subset Cl(A)$ and $X-A \subseteq Cl(X-A)$ 
How do I finish this? Am I on the right track?

Let $x \in Cl(A) \cap Cl(X-A)$ then $x \in Cl(A)$ and $x \in Cl(X-A)$. Where do I go from here?

Comment: have you tried using $Cl(X-A)$ from your definition of $Cl(A)$ and De Morgan laws? $A\subseteq U$ and $X-A\subseteq U$

Comment: Which part of the proof would this help with?

Comment: Hey Alyssa! Last week I helped you prove that $\overline{A} = A\cup                    \text{Bd}(A)$ using the boundary definition $$\text{Bd}(A) = \overline{A}\setminus A^\circ$$ Can you not use that definition of boundary to see that the boundary must be closed?

Comment: I was trying to use this definition to simply say that the intersection of two closed sets is closed

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you use the following standard symbols:

$∂(A)$ is boundary of $A$.

$\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$.

$A^c$ is the complement of $A$.

$A^o$ is the interior of $A$.

$A'$ is the limit point set of $A$.

Boundary is the set whose points are in the closure but not in the interior. So it is defined as
$$
∂(A)= \overline{A} - A^o
$$
Also closure is defined as 
$$
\overline{A}=((A^{c})^o)^c\tag{1}
$$
For complement there is
$$
A^c=X-A \hspace{5 mm}  
$$
And clearly we have
$$
(A^c)^c=X-(X-A)=A\tag{2}
$$
In your case, we have
$$
∂(A)= \overline{A} - A^o=\overline{A} \cap (A^o)^c=\overline{A} \cap \underbrace{(((A^c)^c)^o)^c}_{(1),(2)}=\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}
$$

Comment: Thank you for those recommendations.  I didn't use those particular symbols because that was not the notation I was given out of my textbook or from my professor.